# Get-ADCompter command returns back null response

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to combine a string and an int together to get the output  `JWang1` but everytime I run this command it keeps returning back null, any help is appreciated, thank you

```
$pcname = "Jwang"
$number = 1
Get-ADcomputer -filter "name -like '$pcname + $number'" | select -ExpandProperty name
```

The goal is to get the command to search "JWANG1", but the result keeps coming back null

Alternatively if I do this, I get a search result posted back to me

```
$pcname = "Jwang1"
Get-ADcomputer -filter "name -like '$pcname'" | select -ExpandProperty name
```

The difference here is that I am not trying to combine the string and int, but how do I get it to combine and work?

Comment: In short, you need to either concatenate the 2 values before your query or, enclose your expression in an [Subexpression Operator $(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2). So, `Get-ADcomputer -filter "name -like '$($pcname + $number)'"` will allow the expression to be evaluated within a string.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is how string expansion works, and how you're using it. Right now you have:

```
"name -like '$pcname + $number'"
```

Once you sub in the values for those variables it reads like this:

```
"name -like 'JWANG + 1'"
```

There's several ways you could go about correcting this. The first is to simply remove the `+` from the string so it reads like this:

```
"name -like '$pcname$number'"
```

The second way is to put in a subexpression like this:

```
"name -like '$($pcname + $number)'"
```

Or you could combine them before you reference it like:

```
$pcname = "Jwang"
$number = 1
$combinedname = $pcname + $number
Get-ADcomputer -filter "name -like '$combinedname'" | select -ExpandProperty name
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case you would need to use the [Subexpression operator `$(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#subexpression-operator--) to resolve the concatenation operation:

```
$pcname = "Jwang"
$number = 1

"name -like '$pcname + $number'"
# Interpolates both variables without resolving the concatenation
# Results in: name -like 'Jwang + 1'

"name -like '$($pcname + $number)'"
# Resolves the expression inside `$(..)` before interpolating it
# Results in: name -like 'Jwang1'
```

As aside, the right operator for your query to Active Directory should be `-eq` instead of `-like` since you're not using any wildcard for your query.